# Query information: Some of my Jira fields are empty in Redash

Tags: jira, jql, redash

I am trying to query information from my Jira from Redash.

I already made the connection and it was successful, the problem is that when I try to consult the different tasks from the query editor, (writing `{ }` to get all the information) I can't get all the fields that I DO see if I download the information from Jira in a CSV. In addition to this, there are fields such as the Assignee, which in Redash appear completely empty, despite having content in Jira.

Does anyone know how to help me with this?